# Saving branching possibilities easily (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, path-finding

Since my last question got locked for beeing inprecise, one more try:

Lets say I start at
branch[0]
branch[0] only has an int value of 30.
Now I have two choices. Left or right.
Both have a random chance to multiply/be divided by up to 5.
So left could be 6,8,10,15,30,30,60,90,120,150. Same for right.

This choice happens for up to 30 times for every branch. so 2^30 times.
(disregard the chance of having an insanely large number, it is just an example that is easiest to understand)

Now I want to be able to know which ENDRESULT has the highest value.
AND once I know that, I also need to know the exact path it followed (l,r,l,l,l,r,l...) so I can tell myself at branch[0] which way to go.

HOW can I do this efficiently?
Because every method I thought of is either super complex or would take years to calculate and be super messy. And if possible, this way needs to work with more than just two choices.

*edit*
Example:

I start at a point. That point has gold = 0 as a value.
I have two options. Left and right.

```
Left has gold = 15; Right has gold = 25.
If I go left from the left again (LeftLeft) gold = 25;
If I go right from the left, (LeftRight) gold = 35;
If I go left from the right, (RightLeft) gold = 15;
If I go right from the right again (RightRight) gold = 45;
```

I need to compare the values of LL, LR, RL, RR to each other and once I know that RR has the highest gold, I need to know how I get there from my original starting position.

Comment: Still not clear. You started with *Lets say I start at branch[0]...* and no one has no idea why? please read the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post.

Comment: How? This is not really complicated.
Branch 0 is the startingposition. I need to start somewhere.
Seriously.

Comment: You start at a point. You have two options left and right. These options have more or less random values. I need to know the endresult of every branch and need to know how to get there.

Comment: Just think, if I say same thing like Start with branch[43] and branch[45] and go to branch[60] as a starting point of discussion, what will be your thought? Please specify what branch are you referring to ? is it for a tree? binary tree? or a regular tree or a graph may be? Please try to frame your question as to a person that has never seen this before.

Comment: please read the example. If that doesnt explain it well enough... I might just be too stupid for this world.
And yes it is like a tree.